# Why cant I debug my app in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qml, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator and developing a QML application with a couple of C++ plugins in it. Something that I have yet to figure out is how to actually debug my app. In project settings I have selected *debug*

When I build and then attempt to run the app in debug mode, I get not one but **three** identical prompts, every one of them telling me this:

```
This does not seem to be a "Debug" build.
Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail.

Section .debug_info: Not found.
Section .debug_abbrev: Not found.
Section .debug_line: Not found.
Section .debug_str: Not found.
Section .debug_loc: Not found.
Section .debug_range: Not found.
Section .gdb_index: Not found.
Section .note.gnu.build-id: Found.
Section .gnu.hash: Found.
Section .gnu_debuglink: Not found.
```

Here is my `Effective Qml call` as shown in project settings:

```
qmake /home/aras/Projects/BADASSUI/BADASSUI.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

What am I actually missing?

Comment: For me Qt Creator is always able to debug QML after I just installed it and started some project with QML. Look at the menu Tools / Options / Debuggers and see how gdb is set there. You have a message that gdb_index cannot be found. Also, look at Projects tab on the left and make sure you are building Debug configuration.